# mybatis-guice mysql failed to load jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, guice, mybatis

I'm trying to use **mybatis-guice** with **mysql** but I keep catching the next exception:

**Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error setting driver on UnpooledDataSource. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

**Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Error setting driver on UnpooledDataSource. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver**

Here is the code I try to run:

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao {
    @Inject
    private MyMapper mapper;

    public String getSomething() {
        return mapper.getSomething();
    }
}

public interface Dao {
    String getSomething();
}

public interface MyMapper {
    @Select("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as time")
    String getSomething();
}

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new MyBatisModule() {
            @Override
            protected void initialize() {
                install(JdbcHelper.MySQL);
                environmentId("development");

                bindDataSourceProviderType(PooledDataSourceProvider.class);
                bindTransactionFactoryType(JdbcTransactionFactory.class);
                addMapperClass(MyMapper.class);

                bindProperties(binder(), getMybatisProperties());
                bind(Dao.class).to(DaoImpl.class);
            }
        }
);

private Properties getMybatisProperties() {
    Properties myBatisProperties = new Properties();
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.host", "127.0.0.1");
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.port", "3306");
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.schema", "my_schema");
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.username", "root");
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.password", "");
    myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.autoCommit", "false");
    return myBatisProperties;
}
```

And than I try to run:
`injector.getInstance(Dao.class).getSomething()`

I tried to remove `myBatisProperties.setProperty("JDBC.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"));` but the result was the same.

Also, after several hours of debugging the code, `install(JdbcHelper.MySQL);` should add the driver by itself. Is this assumption correct?

The exception is thrown on `mapper.getSomething();`

Ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a driver mysql-connector-java  or verify the version of the driver and your put mysql-connector-java-bin.jar in the lib